# Is there any way by which we can clone managed package objects or fields?

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, fields, clone

I want to uninstall managed package. Is there any way by which we can clone managed package objects or fields?

Comment: Probably need more information about what you're trying to achieve and why. Is it a managed package you own? Is it an installed managed package, or a managed package under development?

Comment: yeah it's installed managed package.

Comment: I want to uninstall managed package and want to develop my own custom functionality similar to managed package.

Answer (score 1):

Object and fields are always visible in org so prior to do that you can use ANT migration tool, Eclipse IDE to get all objects and fields locally.

Comment: is it possible to clone object/fields using Eclipse IDE?

Comment: I will not use term clone here. but as I said you can download metadata locally and then deploy again in same org and other.